# How to upload an image to server directory?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, file-upload

I'm not sure if this is a bad idea, if it is please let me know, but I want a choose file input to upload to the server's directory. If that didn't make sense, let's say I have a folder for my website and in that I have a public folder and INSTEAD of using databases, upload the image we just submitted to the public folder. Oh and also, this is using node.js and html, no PHP please :)

I've just been doing research on image databases the past few days and couldn't find anything, cough, PHP. I'm trying my best not to pay for stuff as I'm broke.

Thanks, Alek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `multer` will help you. You can set the directory for saving your files.

Comment: In multer, could you upload an unlimited number of files with maxCount?

Comment: with multer().array()